# iOS5: Track Finger and Drag Down View Controller Like Notification Center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

There are two instances that come to mind in the new iOS 5 where a user can drag down to reveal a view. If the user drags down from the status bar at the top of the screen, it will reveal the notification center,

[image: iOS 5 Notification Center]

Also, if the user is in the Weather app and drags down on a specific day of the week, it will reveal the hourly forecast,

[image: iOS 5 Weather app hourly forecast]

Is there a simple drop-in framework that can offer me this functionality? Or is there example code out there on the internet to be able to mimic it?

Comment: The weather app will reveal the hourly forecast simply by tapping on the daily forecast.  It does not require a swipe gesture.

Comment: Yes, but there is a difference when you drag it, you can control the way it is revealed. When you tap it, it just animates down and shows. Do you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: I take it you're referring to the way the reveal animation tracks your finger movement? Can't help you with that.

Comment: Yes, the way it tracks your finger motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone's interested, I've posted up code of how I accomplished this here: [JCWindowShade](https://github.com/johncadengo/JCWindowShade). The relevant code for tracking is here: [handleDrag](https://github.com/johncadengo/JCWindowShade/blob/master/JCWindowShade/JCViewController.m#L137).

Answer (score 3):

What you want to use is a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to detect the swipe and update your UI.

Comment: @awfullyjohn Give me a second to hack something together.

Comment: Don't be lazy @awefullyjohn. the UIGestureRecognizer documentation (from Apple) tell you all about them.

Comment: @JustSid did you ever get a chance to try this out?

Comment: @JustSid Could you guys share it with us? (I'm assumming that there was some example code shared? :P) Thanks!